# Base64 encoding and decoding using Caché Object Script

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

Is there any "built-in" methods or ways to encode/decode to/from BASE64 string in Caché?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To [encode](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.Encryption#METHOD_Base64Encode):
`Write $System.Encryption.Base64Encode("text")`

To [decode](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.Encryption#METHOD_Base64Decode):
`Write $System.Encryption.Base64Decode("dGV4dA==")`

Note: Base 64 encoding is not able to encode a string which contains unicode (2 byte) characters. If you need to Base 64 encode an unicode string, you should first translate the string to UTF8 format, then encode it.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Exactly what I needed. Wondering why search through the native Caché documentation gives nothing within "base64".

Comment: @ZitRo search all the system code (start with *.cls, *.mac after that) in Studio via "Search in files". It gives you not only results, but code examples at the same time.

Comment: Good point! But this tricky solution works only if you know exact "keywords" for search :)

Comment: I'm impressed with intersystems documentation overall but the search doesn't seem to work well.  Perhaps try the PDF version instead of the HTML version of the docs?

Comment: Or better yet, you can Google `base64 site:http://docs.intersystems.com/`!  The first result on that search has your answer.  The same search term in their search doesn't return the document at all!